# Alternative proof to 4.26 in Axler’s MIRA?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

The lemma 4.26 states the the following:

> Suppose G is a nonempty open subset of $\mathbb{R}$. Then there exists a closed set $F \subset G \setminus \mathbb{Q}$ such that $\left|F\right| > 0$.

In his proof he constructs such a set by removing from a closed interval $J$ contained in G exponentially decreasing open balls around the rationals of $J$.

When I tried to prove this theorem before reading his proof, I simply said, that due to the (inner) regularity of the Lebesgue measure, and due to the fact that $\mathbb{Q}$ is a null set, there exists a compact (and thus closed, since $\mathbb{R}$ is Hausdorff) set, that has measure larger than say $\frac{\left|G\right|}{2}= \frac{\left|G \setminus \mathbb{Q}\right|}{2} > 0$.

Does this sound right?

Comment: Your argument is correct, however, if I remember correctly, at the point of the book where we have lemma 4.26, the inner regularity of Lebesgue measure is not yet proved.